# Change legend in Highcharts Heatmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[In this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pzn4go9w/) I have a Highcharts HeatMap with a legend that goes from 0 to 150. How can I change it to go from -150 to 150?

```
legend: {
    align: 'right',
    layout: 'vertical',
    margin: 0,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    symbolHeight: 280,
},
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. The range in your sample data is 0...132, so with some padding the heatmap range is automatically set to 0...150. Why -150...150, e.g. why assign colors to a non-existing data range?

Comment: If you want to set the minimum and maximum color use `colorAxis: { minColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', maxColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify settings for color-axis, for example:

```
  colorAxis: {
    min: -150,
    max: 150,
    tickInterval: 50,
    ...
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/86scdw73/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/color-axis